Can we improve the way MathOverflow links appear on BlueSky?
I sometimes share MathOverflow posts on Twitter and now also on BlueSky, which seems to be appreciated. I have noticed, however, that the manner in which BlueSky interprets the MathOverflow image is not so great.

It is chopping up the MO icon and showing just a part of it, in a way that conveys no useful information. I have seen many other links on BlueSky to MO, and they all appear with this same unfortunate graphic.
I find this less than ideal, but I have no idea how to set things up with the MO website so that BlueSky gets a useful image. So my question is:
Question. Can we set things up here on MO so that BlueSky posts will show a more relevant MathOverflow image?
After posting this question, I shared it on BlueSky, and I noticed that the situation for meta posts is even worse:

I have no idea what BlueSky posts to other stackexchange sites are like, but it seems likely that this is a system-wide problem, which should be fixed system-wide.

I have no idea what "BlueSky" is, but based on the screenshots, the main problem is that it insists on showing every embedded post with a huge irrelevant image even if there is no image in the post conveying any useful information. This is not going to be fixed if this huge image displays properly the MO logo; it simply should not be there. This is a BlueSky bug (and bad design decision), and the only one who can fix it is BlueSky.

@EmilJeřábek BlueSky is a lot like Twitter, if you've heard of that. I disagree with your points here, since the way Twitter used to handle MO posts worked well with the MO logo. Also, I find it very sound practice to post such relevant images in connection with such posts online, and this is indeed the practice of essentially all the social media systems. (In particular, not all images posted on BlueSky are the same size.) BlueSky is using the image that we give it, so let us give it a more suitable image.

The problem of arranging suitable images to appear on Twitter, bsky, etc. is a problem that every blogger knows about, and WordPress, Substack, etc. all have ways for users to control that and default settings etc. This is a problem that stackexchange needs to solve.

Based on experiments with other stackexchange sites, Bsky seems to be grabbing the favicon image (the tiny image that appears in the tab of the browser) rather than any image in the post. Perhaps what needs to happen is to set a key so that it grabs the logo banner, which would be much better.

I don’t know how it appears in your browser, but the MathOverflow favicon actually displays a shortened version of the logo (with “mo” in place of the full word “mathoverflow”), and the favicon of meta.MO is the same except the orange colour turns grey. So if you are right, that indicates another bug of Bluesky, namely that the image processing it uses to enlarge the image is broken.

Yes, part of my question is concerning what image it is that bsky is using, since it is obviously an MO image but isn't the logo and isn't the favicon exactly (but on other stackexchange sites it is clearly the favicon). In any case, we don't want it using the favicon image at all. I expect that there are already many thousands of Bsky posts linking to stackexchange questions and answers, and more to come, and so this is a problem worth solving. I believe we might solve it on our end by setting a key in some html. Your proposal to sit back and blame Bsky seems, frankly, useless.

My proposal is not to blame Bluesky, but to direct this bug report to their support forum, or whatever they have to intercept bug reports. Trying to fix someone else’s bugs by workarounds is generally not very productive.

If indeed this is a BlueSky bug, then I agree. But it seems to me more likely that we are simply not telling them properly which image we want them to use. Setting the right information in the header or whatever is not a "workaround" but rather just fixing things to work properly.

The page OpenGraph metadata currently tell all sites that want to use an icon to use https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=f1c9606b77ff for the main site and https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathoverflowmeta/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=d3962dcee6be for meta. The problem is that they have transparent backgrounds, and BlueSky is blitting them on black and then cropping the top and bottom off.

It seems like these images are OK for icons, but not for use as featured images, which is what is needed here.

I'm with Emil here in thinking that what's needed is to remove the metadata entirely and not have featured images, but someone at StackExchange must have thought they were a good idea and I have no expectation that StackExchange cares in the slightest about our opinions on the matter.

If the problem only appears on BSky, then the problem is there, not here. On mathstodon (a Mastodon instance with lots of mathematicians) there is no problem see eg https://mathstodon.xyz/@thosgood/113676589336150537

I haven't had a X/Twitter account for a while, so I can't properly experience what that site looks like any more. Picking a random tweet I found, there's no preview at all: https://x.com/JDHamkins/status/1836199043539841519
